# How to setup spring project reconnect automatically after losing the jdbc connection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I have a project which is running in java 1.8 and spring 1.x, It runs finely without any errors. But I just want to handle the error happens when it loose the DB connection.

I kill the process to test using sudo kill and then it give typical jdbc connection error.

```
Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:242)
```

I want to handle this and want to reconnect the DB. I'm new to spring. And also this finely work after I restart the application. It again create jdbc connection and work finely.

And this is the properties file

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false

# HikariCP configuration
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=20 
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=30000 

spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=20
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=SpringBootJPAHikariCP
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=2000000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000

# Database connection details
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/octopus_retaildemo
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=retaildemo
spring.datasource.password=demo
#spring.jpa.database=default

autocount.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/aed_foroctopustestdata
autocount.datasource.username=pasinduprabhath
autocount.datasource.password=demo
autocount.datasource.default_schema=public
autocount.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=false


octopus.directoryPath=/Users/pasinduprabhath/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.19.1.RELEASE/Sentinal/reports

octopus.testmode=0
octopus.maxpoolsize=20
octopus.terminal=HQ001
octopus.location=HQ
octopus.username=admin

octopus.invjob.enabled=false
octopus.invjob.attachzip=0
octopus.invjob.time=1 * * * * *

octopus.autocount.enabled=true

octopus.autocount.salescsvread.enabled=false
octopus.autocount.salescsvread.readtime=1 * * * * *
octopus.autocount.salescsvread.salesfilename=POS Sales Transaction
octopus.autocount.salescsvread.salesfilename.columns=dateTime,empty1,documentNo,itemCode,description,qty,unitPrice,gross,discount,subTotal,tax,totalEx,totalInc
#octopus.autocount.salescsvread.paymentfilename=Sale Receipt by payment
octopus.autocount.salescsvread.paymentfilename=Cash Receipt Report 
octopus.autocount.salescsvread.paymentfilename.columns=documentDate,documentNo,totalEx,tax,total,roundAdj,finalTotal,cashPayment,creditCardPayment,debitCardPayment,chequePayment,voucherPayment,pointPayment,creditPayment
octopus.autocount.salescsvread.customerfilename=Customer Transaction
octopus.autocount.salescsvread.customerfilename.columns=date,docNo,customerid,customerName,email
octopus.autocount.salescsvread.hpenabled=false

pos.customer.point.job.enabled=false
pos.customer.point.job.time=1 * * * * *
logging.file=sentinal.log
logging.level.root=INFO

octopus.autocount.readitemenabled=true
octopus.autocount.readitemtable=1 * * * * *

octopus.autocount.doreadenabled=false
octopus.autocount.readdotable=1 * * * * *
#octopus.autocount.readitemtable=0 0/1 * * * *

# Reconnect properties
spring.datasource.hikari.initialization-fail-fast=true
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-init-sql=SELECT 1
```

I just tried with a class(ConnectionValidator class)

```
package com.octopus.services.common.network;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.Application;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

@Component
public class ConnectionValidator {

    private final DataSource dataSource;
    private int maxReconnectAttempts = 3; // Maximum number of reconnection attempts
    private int reconnectAttemptInterval = 3000; // Interval between reconnection attempts in milliseconds
    
    @Autowired
    public ConnectionValidator(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 50000) // Run every minute
    public void validateConnection() {
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            // Perform a simple query to validate the connection
            JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
            jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT 1", Integer.class);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // Handle the exception (e.g., attempt to reconnect)
            if (isConnectionClosedException(e)) {
                reconnect();
            } else {
                // Handle other types of SQLExceptions as needed
                log.error("Error occurred during connection validation:", e);
            }
        }
    }
    
    private boolean isConnectionClosedException(SQLException e) {
        return e.getMessage() != null && e.getMessage().contains("This connection has been closed");
    }

    private void handleReconnectionFailure() {
        System.err.println("Failed to reconnect after max attempts. Performing custom action...");
    }
    
    private void reconnect() {
        int reconnectAttempts = 0;
        while (reconnectAttempts < maxReconnectAttempts) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(reconnectAttemptInterval);
                Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
                if (connection.isValid(5)) { // Check if the reconnected connection is valid
                    return;
                }
            } catch (SQLException | InterruptedException ex) {
                log.error("Reconnection attempt failed:", ex);
            }
            reconnectAttempts++;
        }
        handleReconnectionFailure();
    }
}
```

like above and calling it in main. Here is the main,

```
package com;

import java.io.IOException;
import com.octopus.pos.utils.DatabaseManager;
import com.octopus.services.common.network.ConnectionValidator;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersInvalidException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRestartException;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource("file:application.properties")
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Application.class);
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws BeansException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException,
            JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException, InterruptedException, IOException {

        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.setWebEnvironment(false);
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = app.run(args);
        
         Application application = ctx.getBean(Application.class);
         ConnectionValidator connectionValidator = ctx.getBean(ConnectionValidator.class);
         log.info("PP calling validation");
         connectionValidator.validateConnection();
    }   

}
```

But it still gives the same jdbc error. Can someone tell me what can I do to fix this? I just want to reconnect when DB connection killed.
I'm using postgres DB. And tried both **Apache Commons DBCP** and the HikariCP.